# Delete subdirectory folder while saving contents

Tags: command-line, files, rm

Lets say I have the directory `/Users/admin/Documents/Folder1/file1.txt` and would like to delete `Folder1` without also deleting `file1.txt`. In the end it should look like `/Users/admin/Documents/file1.txt`.

Comment: Is `file1` really a directory, as stated in your question? If it's a file, then does it represent a collection of files, or just itself? (Please [edit or update](http://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/223978/edit) your question to address this, rather than responding in comments.)

Answer (score 1):

You have to do that in two steps:

```
mv /Users/admin/Documents/Folder1/file1.txt /Users/admin/Documents/file1.txt
rm -R /Users/admin/Documents/Folder1
```

With `bash` you can do the following shorter version:

```
mv /Users/admin/Documents/{Folder1/,}file1.txt
rm -R /Users/admin/Documents/Folder1
```

Comment: For a more automated way (and save directory removal), I'd suggest: `mv /dir/subdir/{.[^.]*,*,} ; rmdir /dir/subdir` - will print a negligible error if there is no `.`-file, but otherwise get them all. The `rmdir` is saver as the dir has to be empty.

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is try to copy the .txt file to the documents directory. Then you can go ahead and delete the sub-directory. That would be 100X easier.

Answer (score -2):

Originally I had suggested this:

```
cd /Users/admin/Documents/Folder1
mv $(ls -A) .. # the -A will find hidden items, but not return "." or ".."
cd ..
rmdir Folder1
```

But from the comments, I see that is not safe.

Comment: Be very careful with using `ls` in a script! Have a read of this discussion: [link](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls)

Comment: Hm! Learn something new every day.